# Order custom post type by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

to all i have tried by this code to sort my list custom post type by a specific category in ASC way:  (i have "model" custom post type and i wanna show order by "model-year" taxonomy

```
 function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

 // do not modify queries in the admin
 if( is_admin() ) {

return $query;

}

// only modify queries for 'model' post type
if ( $query->is_tax( 'model-year' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {

$query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
$query->set('meta_key', '');    
$query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
}

// return
return $query;

 }

 add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Meta key value:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    // only modify queries for 'model' post type
    if ( $query->is_tax( 'model-year' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value'); 

        // Add Metakey ( "Custome field name" );  
        $query->set('meta_key', 'order_number');    
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: this is my csutom type and taxonomy (see screen) https://prnt.sc/1sobl0w, how u can see i have some years then i wanna show post starting from oldest year and then new